# Bash - Split the previous commands parameters

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk, command-history

How would one parse the previous command in bash?

**Example:**

```
root$ ssh foo@1.2.3.4
root$ echo !$ &>/tmp/foo.txt
root$ cat /tmp/foo.txt
foo@1.2.3.4
```

**Goal:**
Send just the ipaddress  `1.2.3.4` to foo.txt

---

I've attempted to used awk, but have not found success

```
#doesn't work
cat /tmp/foo.txt |awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'
```

I've also attempted to parse out just the digits using sed

```
#doesn't work
sed 's/.//p' /tmp/foo.txt 
sed 's/[0-9]//p' /tmp/foo.txt
```

**Considerations**
1.2.3.4 will always be a number between 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255
The user name `foo` can be any length
foo@1.2.3.4 is *not* necessarily the only parameter passed into ssh (eg.. ssh 1.2.3.4 -l foo)

**Resources**

- [how to use sed, awk, or gawk to print only what is matched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733692/how-to-use-sed-awk-or-gawk-to-print-only-what-is-matched)
- [How to output only captured groups with sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777579/sed-group-capturing)
- [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

**Further Clarification**
The end goal will be to create a function in my .bashrc that will allow me to easily remove a conflicting ssh key.

```
root$ ssh foo@1.2.3.4  
#some big error message warning about man in the middle attack
root$ ssh-keygen -R 1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your original syntax:
`$ cat /tmp/foo.txt | awk -F@ '{print $2}'`
`1.2.3.4`

Comment: @John. `cat` is not needed.  `awk -F@ '{print $2}' /tmp/foo.txt` does the same without invoking `cat`

Comment: Canonical http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uucaletter

Answer (score 1):

If you can use another syntax for the ssh command, it get's easier:

```
ssh -l foo 1.2.3.4 
echo !:3
```

but this requires this exact syntax.

Comment: +1, This is a good idea. Very elegant.  I'd prefer to not retrain myself to use the -l every time tough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!!` to access the previous command line so

```
echo !! | sed 's/.*@\(.*\).*/\1/' | awk '{print $1}'
```

may work for you e.g.

```
echo ssh user@123.456.654.321 ls | ...
123.456.654.321

echo ssh -p 19111 user@123.456.654.321 | ...
123.456.654.321
```

The only assumption here is that the ipaddress will be preceded by an @ and that there is a space or end of line after it.

Answer (score 0):

When you had print output to a file, I will use Perl:

```
cat /tmp/foo.txt | \
perl -ne ' print $& if $_ =~ /(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)/'
```

Answer (score 0):

To find a numeric IP address from the previous ssh command:

```
echo $(grep -oP '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' <<< "!ssh")
```

I don't see anything in the manual that would let you find "an argument matching a pattern" (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction)

Pretty sure you can't put `!`-style history expansions inside a function, but there's the `fc` command:

```
# return the IP address of the most recent ssh command
sship () { command grep -oP '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+' < <(fc -l ssh); }
```

This will not constrain you to have the ip address as a specific (e.g. the last) argument

```
ssh user@1.2.3.4 hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no history expansion construct to break at `@`. However the last argument of the previous command is also available as the variable `$_`.

```
ssh-keygen -R "${_##*@}"
```

Note that this only works if the host name was the last argument of the previous command: it won't work if the previous command was e.g. `ssh somehost ls`. You can attempt parsing the output of `fc -ln -1` to extract the first non-option argument.

---

Your goal strikes me as a rather bad idea. It is rare to need to remove an SSH host key — basically it should only happen if the machine has been reinstalled. If you need to do that often, something is wrong with your methodology, or perhaps with your network setup (make sure that your DHCP clients get reproducible IP addresses unless you're never ever going to connect to them from another machine).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Myself and others create and destroy dozens of openstack instances per week for testing. You can see additional details about why I get so many conflicting ssh keys on this question http://serverfault.com/questions/506864/turn-off-strict-checking-of-ssh-keys